# npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY for typescript@4.5.5 when using win-64 msi

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Edit: I’ve discovered that this happens only with the 64-bit windows msi installer and not the 32-bit msi installer

I've tried everything listed in other answers.

- delete package-lock.json  (can't doesn't exist)
- delete node_modules (didn't help)
- npm cache verify (didn't help, says "corrupted content removed" every time)
- npm cache clean --force (didn't help)
- delete AppData/Local/npm-cache (didn't help)
- delete AppData/Roaming/npm (didn't help)
- npm i -g npm (didn't help)
- npm config set package-lock false (didn't help)
- I reset my machine to a fresh install of Win 10 and Win 11 (didn't help)
- I disabled auto-proxy (didn't help)

It always fails for typescript@4.5.5.  I have no idea what else to do, and I can't install angular/cli with this failure.

- what is the sha512 for typescript@4.5.5 supposed to be?
- can I disable EINTEGRITY checks?
- are there any other solutions I missed?

> $ npm i
> npm WARN tarball tarball data for esbuild-wasm@0.14.14 (sha512-qTjK4MWnYtQHCMGg2qDUqeFYXfVvYq5qJkQTIsOV4VZCknoYePVaDTG9ygEB9Ct0kc0DWs7IrS6Ja+GjY62Kzw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
>
> ... several more "seems to be corrupted"
>
> npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@4.5.5 (sha512-TCTIul70LyWe6IJWT8QSYeA54WQe8EjQFU4wY52Fasj5UKx88LNYKCgBEHcOMOrFF1rKGbD8v/xcNWVUq9SymA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
>
> npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
> npm ERR! sha512-TCTIul70LyWe6IJWT8QSYeA54WQe8EjQFU4wY52Fasj5UKx88LNYKCgBEHcOMOrFF1rKGbD8v/xcNWVUq9SymA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-TCTIul70LyWe6IJWT8QSYeA54WQe8EjQFU4wY52Fasj5UKx88LNYKCgBEHcOMOrFF1rKGbD8v/xcNWVUq9SymA== but got sha512-U0dCcrUYPNLvBHhB3AuhIqz7zrcg2z2u5LCqmZVNN/aUqimo+p2cVyQ1kFsbc9XMmh8tNFcOkuY0itp0Yz31fQ==. (11280693 bytes)
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\chuck\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-10T02_23_03_444Z-debug-0.log

Possibly related, every time I verify my cache, it thinks new contents are corrupted and removes them

> c:\Users\chuck\git\test>npm cache verify
> Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)
> Content verified: 45 (10072506 bytes)
> Index entries: 70
> Finished in 0.151s
>
> c:\Users\chuck\git\test>npm cache verify
> Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)
> Content verified: 44 (10066799 bytes)
> Corrupted content removed: 1
> Content garbage-collected: 1 (5707 bytes)
> Missing content: 2
> Index entries: 68
> Finished in 0.188s
>
> c:\Users\chuck\git\test>npm cache verify
> Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)
> Content verified: 40 (9155292 bytes)
> Corrupted content removed: 4
> Content garbage-collected: 4 (911507 bytes)
> Missing content: 6
> Index entries: 62
> Finished in 0.178s
>
> c:\Users\chuck\git\test>npm cache verify
> Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)
> Content verified: 37 (8712984 bytes)
> Corrupted content removed: 3
> Content garbage-collected: 3 (442308 bytes)
> Missing content: 4
> Index entries: 58
> Finished in 0.155s

It's like sha512 is a random number generator

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I uninstalled the 64bit node and reinstalled with the 32bit version for windows, and all my corruption and EINTEGRITY errors are now gone!